# Редактор CKEditor не отправляет данные из формы с первого раза, а только со второго

Tags: ckeditor

Привет.
Не могу понять, почему при нажатии кнопки "Отправить" сначала выдает ошибку, что не все поля заполнены (хотя это не так), а при повторном нажатии отправляет форму.
Прикрутил CKEditor на поле textarea. Сам редактор работает, но вот данные отправляет со второго раза. Что делать? Форма сделана на Contact Form 7.

Ссылка на сайте (там можете протестировать форму. Обязательных полей нет. Форма внизу страницы):
http://voice.lightmuzikmastering.ru

Comment: @Victor Slate, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Неверно, видимо, прикручен ckEditor. Он должен копировать при вводе информацию в поле textarea и, видимо, этого не делает. А когда отправка формы идет - делает. На вторую отправку поле textarea оказывается заполненым и форма отправляется. Это как идея, на что обратить внимание.